# Can I write a hash function say `hashit(a, b, c)` taking no more than O(N) space

Tags: hashmap, hashtable

Given integers a,b,c such that

```
-N<=a<=N,
0<=b<=N,
0<=c<=10
```

Can I write a hash function say `hashit(a, b, c)` taking no more than O(N) adrdress space.

My naive thought was to write it as,
`a+2N*b+10*2N*N*c`
thats like O(20N*N) space, so it wont suffice my need.

let me elaborate my usecase, I want tuple `(a,b,c)` as key of a hashmap . Basically a,b,c are arguments to my function which I want to memorise. in python `@lru_cache` perfectly does it without any issue for N=1e6 but when I try to write hash function myself I get memory overflow. So how do python do it ?

I am working wih N of the order of 10^6

This code work

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def myfn(a,b,c):
    //some logic
    return 100
```

But if i write the hash function myself like this, it doesn't . So how do python do it.

```
def hashit(a,b,c):
    return a+2*N*b+2*N*N*c

def myfn(a,b,c):
    if hashit(a,b,c) in myhashtable:
        return myhashtable[hashit(a,b,c)]
    //some logic
    myhashtable[hashit(a,b,c)] = 100;
    return myhashtable[hashit(a,b,c)]
```

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand the problem,  but a simple XOR hash takes O(1) space

Comment: @PMF I need unique value, there should be no collison any any two tuples

Comment: @PMF if tuple `(a_i,b_i,c_i)` and tuple `(a_j,b_j,c_j)` generates the same hash value it beats my purpose.

Comment: It's literally impossible to map a domain of size O(N^2) to one of size O(N) without collisions.

Comment: @kaya3 ok let me elaborate my usecase, I want tuple `(a,b,c)` as key of a hashmap . Basically a,b,c are arguments to my function which I want to memorise. in python `@lru_cache` perfectly does it without any issue for N=1e6 but when I try to write hash function myself I get memory overflow. So how do python do it ?

Comment: Please add all of the relevant information to your question, including a [mcve]. If you are just putting tuples of integers into Python dictionaries or sets, it is not clear why you think you need to write your own hash function in the first place. It also doesn't make much sense that a tuple of three integers would cause an out-of-memory error, so you need to show us exactly what you are doing and what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use tuples directly as keys in Python dictionaries? There does not seem to be any need for your `hashit` function at all, just write `myhashtable[a, b, c]`.

Comment: @kaya3 yes I am. But Now Iam trying to implement it myself. If python stdlib is able to do it, why wouldn't I be.

Comment: Python's standard library doesn't use a collision-free hash function; it uses equality checks on the actual keys (not their hashes) to resolve collisions.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question of whether it is possible to find an injective hash function from a set of size `Θ(N^2)` to a set of size `O(N)`: it isn't. The very existence of an injective function from a finite set A to a set B implies that `|B| >= |A|`. This is similar to trying to give a unique number out of `{1, 2, 3}` to each member of a group of 20 people.

However, do note that hash functions *do* oftentimes have collisions; the hash tables that employ them simply have a method for resolving those collisions. As one simple example for clarification, you could for instance hold an array such that every possible output of your hash function is mapped to an index of this array, and at each index you have a list of elements (so an array of lists where the array is of size `O(N)`), and then in the case of a collision simply go over all elements in the matching list and compare them (not their hashes) until you find what you're looking for. This is known as *chain hashing* or *chaining*. Some rare manipulations (*re-hashing*) on the hash table based on how populated it is (measured through its *load factor*) could ensure an **amortized** time complexity of `O(1)` for element access, but this could over time increase your space complexity if you actually try to hold `ω(N)` values, though do note that this is unavoidable: you can't use less space than `Θ(X)` to hold `Θ(X)` values without any extra information (for instance: if you hold 1000000 unordered elements where each is a natural number between 1 and 10, then you could simply hold ten counters; but in your case you describe a whole possible set of elements of size `11*(N+1)*(2N+1)`, so `Θ(N^2)`).

This method would, however, ensure a space complexity of `O(N+K)` (equivalent to `O(max{N,K})`) where K is the amount of elements you're holding; so long as you aren't trying to simultaneously hold `Θ(N^2)` (or however many you deem to be too many) elements, it would probably suffice for your needs.